# php оператор continue

Tags: php

```
for( $i=1992;$i<=date('Y');$i++ ) {
    echo "  |   ";
    if( $i==$_GET ['year'])
        echo "<a href='$PHP_SELF?year=$i' class='active' >$i</a>";
    else
       echo "<a href='$PHP_SELF?year=$i'>$i</a>";
}
```

Хочу исключить несколько цифр в годах.

Comment: и что получается?

Comment: if( $i=='1995' and $i=='1996')

Comment: не не получается

Comment: for( $i=1992;$i<=date('Y');$i++ ){
    echo " | ";
    if( $i=='1995' and $i=='1996')
        
          echo "<a href='$PHP_SELF?year=$i' class='active' >$i</a>";
    else
    echo "<a href='$PHP_SELF?year=$i'>$i</a>";
   }

Comment: for( $i=1992;$i<=date('Y');$i++ ) {
    echo "  |   ";
    if( $i=='1995' or $i=='1996'){
        echo 'propustil'.'<br>';
    }
    else{
       echo $i.'<br>';
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

Если вы уже знаете про оператор `continue`, то в чем же проблема его применить? Соберите годы, которые хотите пропустить в отдельный массив, и пропускайте

```
$skip = [2000,2001];
foreach(range(1992, date("Y")) as $y){
   if(in_array($y, $skip)) continue;
   .... 
}
```

Comment: Пишеть Parse error

Comment: на первую строку что ли?

Comment: да на $skip = [2000,2001];

Comment: `$skip = array(2000,2001);` переходите уже на 7й пхп

Comment: for( $i=1992;$i<=date('Y');$i++ ){
    echo " | ";
    if( $i==$_GET['year'])
    $skip = [2000,2001];
foreach(range(1992, date("Y")) as $y){
   if(in_array($y, $skip)) continue     
          echo "<a href='$PHP_SELF?year=$i' class='active' >$i</a>";
    else
    echo "<a href='$PHP_SELF?year=$i'>$i</a>";
   }

Comment: for( $i=1992;$i<=date('Y');$i++ ){
    echo " | ";
    if( $i==$_GET['year'])
    $skip = array = [2000,2001];
foreach(range(1992, date("Y")) as $y){
   if(in_array($y, $skip)) continue     
          echo "<a href='$PHP_SELF?year=$i' class='active' >$i</a>";
    else
    echo "<a href='$PHP_SELF?year=$i'>$i</a>";
   }

Comment: версия php5.2 походу из за этого :)

Comment: @Yazmurad Пожалуйста, вносите код не в комментарии, а в вопрос -- форматирование кода в комментариях не поддерживается, пожалейте глаза коллег, которым это читать придётся.